# How can I get the key and value types out of a Map<unknown,unknown>?

Tags: typescript

e.g. I'm trying to write a function like this:

```
export function fpMapSet<M extends Map<unknown,unknown>>(key: KEY_TYPE, value: VALUE_TYPE) {
```

Where `KEY_TYPE` ought to be whatever that first `unknown` actually is, and `VALUE_TYPE` should be the 2nd `unknown`.

And yes, I know I can write it like this:

```
export function fpMapSet<K,V>(key: K, value: V) {
```

But that's not the question.

Comment: this is where `infer` can be helpful.

Comment: Are you planning to explicitly instantiate `M` when you call `fpMapSet`?  That's what I've done in my answer.  If not I don't think you'll get reasonable behavior (since only after the compiler knows `M` could it constrain the types of `key` or `value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the question as asked, you could use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) via `infer` to extract the key and value types:

```
type MapKeyType<M> = M extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
type MapValueType<M> = M extends Map<any, infer V> ? V : never;
declare function fpMapSet<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>>(
  key: MapKeyType<M>, value: MapValueType<M>): void;
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
const fpMapSetStringNumber = fpMapSet<Map<string, number>>;
// const fpMapSetStringNumber: (key: string, value: number) => void
```

The above is an [instantiation expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) showing how you can set `M` to `Map<string, number>` and leave the function uncalled.  You can of course call instantiate `M` and call the function at the same time:

```
fpMapSet<Map<string, number>>("abc", 123);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsgQwgaSmAKpKAeOA+GAXnhigA8QoA7AEwGd4lsBLKgMygCcZkAaGBFTAEA-DxgAuGFSgA3LgG5QWRhABqCADYBXKJmi4CxOKQrV6q7ILD9WHbmtEw1k6XMXAaUAMaaEnWDZtKm8QZgB7Khg2CEQIAGUoEFxTSloGOOxggGsqcIB3Kn4cvMK8PAAKbLQpONQMLEN+WS1dWqQNHT1G-ABKKVlw5holYG9IuhBo2KREkHiQTlYAcwA5bQBbACMuImm4udwmSaWqZf4qTZ3OcqUAejuYcapJ-dmkhdO1q64pKpqYCcVs1WlApJdtlxekQCINhsBgDEDkkjhBsECzhcfjdKgAiBBbby4-gARgATABmXoKIA)